# SwiftyStoreKit - How to properly restore auto renewable subscriptions?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, swiftystorekit

So I have a really basic concept of auto-renewable subscriptions in the app which unlocks PRO functionality. 
I also have a non-consumable purchase which is a "one-time purchase subscription" which unlocks the PRO functionality once and forever.

What I can't wrap my head around is, when I call `restorePurchases` (using **SwiftyStoreKit**) it brings in all purchases that were ever made by a user. Those may include multiple purchases of the same subscription which were expired long ago.

What I do next is I call a `verifyPurchase` method on each of those restored purchases and that method checks expiration date of each subscription that was ever purchased and if it is expired - it takes away the PRO from the user by clearing keychain (as it thinks that the current subscription got expired):

```
  case .expired(let expiryDate, let items):
             log.info("Subscription has expired on \(expiryDate)")
             log.debug(items)
             self.activeSubscription = nil
             self.clearStore()
             seal.reject(SubscriptionServiceError.expired(on: expiryDate))
  }
```

So what currently happens in my app is even if a user has an active subscription, if he or she tries to `restorePurchases`, there is a chance that `verifyPurchase` last purchase to verify would be an expired subscription, resulting in a canceled PRO version of the app for the user, even with an active subscription on board.

What would be the best practice to avoid this mistake and always verify the one and only right subscription?

Comment: If you plan to do in app auto renewable subscriptions and make more than 100$ from the app, you absolutely should be having your own backend server that does all the logic there along with server hooks and receipt refreshing. 

See more @ https://medium.com/@chriseelmaa/implementing-in-app-subscriptions-for-ios-and-android-b36a29482faa

Answer (score 3):

From the [SwiftyStoreKit docs](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit#verify-subscription):

```swift
let purchaseResult = SwiftyStoreKit.verifySubscription(
        ofType: .autoRenewable, // or .nonRenewing (see below)
        productId: productId,
        inReceipt: receipt)

    switch purchaseResult {
    case .purchased(let expiryDate, let items):
        print("\(productId) is valid until \(expiryDate)\n\(items)\n")
    case .expired(let expiryDate, let items):
        print("\(productId) is expired since \(expiryDate)\n\(items)\n")
    case .notPurchased:
        print("The user has never purchased \(productId)")
    }
```

It looks like you would pass in the product Id to determine if a specific subscription is still active.

You probably don't want to do this on every app launch so you should cache the result somewhere - all you need is probably the expiration date.

Comment: If we have multiple product then ?

Comment: if you have multiple products read this: https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit/wiki/Subscription-Groups